# Wrong result through Sizeof a char array

Tags: c, sizeof

I get a result of `-858993460` through `sizeof()` it should be `10`. 
Im coding in C:

```
fscanf(pFile, "%20s", input);

i_sizeOfInput = (sizeof(input) / sizeof(char));
```

`i_sizeOfInput` is `-858993460.`

Any idears?

Comment: can you please show the declaration of `i_sizeOfInput` so we know exactly what type it is?

Comment: How is input declared? Anyway `strlen` is the way to have the length of a string.

Comment: And, how do you actually **get** the value of `i_sizeOfInput`? Through `printf()`, through debugger output?

Comment: Input is a CSV file, the first line was Frank:5342

Comment: int i_sizeOfInput = 0; char input[] = { ' ' };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the length of a string you must use [strlen](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm)

```
In your case i_sizeOfInput = strlen(input);
```

The sizeof operator returns the size in bytes of its operand.

**EDIT**

Reading recent comments I must add that  declaring your input variable in that way (`char input[] = { ' ' };` )you are invoking [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As you can see you are declaring an array with a space of 1 char and `fscanf` ca return a lot of bytes that will be placed out of bounds of `input` variable.

You must define input as large as the maximun dimention of strings that can be read from file, e.g `char input[128] = {'\0'};`

Comment: @Y.N Then close the question as answered.